# How to properly define font size

Tags: html, css

I try to get a `span` element with an exactly defined height (in this example `23px`). However, the browser adds some pixels to the element.

There is no `padding` and no `margin`, it's the actual text that is bigger. How do I get the text height (and with it also the `span` height) to `23px`?

Requirements:

- No trial and error (or other method) to figure out some arbitrary number beside 23px to get it to work.
- The entire text needs to stay within the border of the span (regardless of the text inside).
- The method must intuitively work, if text wraps. (I.e. element size will be 46px with two lines, 69px with three lines etc.)

```css
span {
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 23px;
  border: red dashed 1px;
}
```

```html
<span>This element is ...x28 (...x30 with border), but should be ...x23 (...x25 with border).</span>
```

Comment: You can't do that right now. You'd need to perform a calculation based on the 23px and the ascent and descent font metrics. But currently, CSS does not expose the font metrics for that calculation. I believe that there are plans to expose the font metrics, although I'm not sure what form they will take. No browsers support it, anyway.

Comment: If you post this as answer, I can accept it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given by Alohci in a comment:

You can't do that right now. You'd need to perform a calculation based on the 23px and the ascent and descent font metrics. But currently, CSS does not expose the font metrics for that calculation. I believe that there are plans to expose the font metrics, although I'm not sure what form they will take. No browsers support it, anyway.